# Parse API GET Request

Tags: json, rest

If I have a Parse.com API with applicationId APPLICATION_ID and REST-API-Key REST_API_KEY, and the classname is Story, then what should the GET request structure look like. I tried the following :

https://api.parse.com/1/story/applicationId=APPLICATION_ID&REST-API-Key=REST_API_KEY

but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Are you receiving an error.  I know nothing of parse.com, but I suspect your URL should be `story?applicationId` instead of `story/applicationId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Das According to [Parse API](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide)
Authentication is done via **HTTP headers**.
So, your request should be

1. *GET /1/stories/story HTTP/1.1 
    Host : api.parse.com
2. Accept: application/json
3. X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID
4. X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REST_API_KEY*

When we need to use headers, the Get request can not be formed within a single URL, 
[Postman](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwigpYWdn6bIAhWNC44KHV5EAl4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fpostman%2Ffhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNE_Yq59TT1ZExzJ68FTldg4ho_lGw&sig2=s7VyvPN06NHpqBuHYe5opA) chrome extension would be helpful to construct the requests
or fiddler.
When you are using postman, to fill the header details, take the HTTP Verb as POST and use 
X-Http-Method-Override: GET header to make it a GET request.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I sent the request to https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Creation with the required headers using Postman and it worked!!